# How can I implement a faster loop through email suggestions in a dropdown (UL) using Java Selenium?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, automation, dropdown

I am automating a task with Selenium where I enter different letter combinations into the Gmail input field. As I type, a dropdown appears with email suggestions based on the input. I want to capture these email suggestions for each letter combination.

Currently, I'm using the following code to loop through and capture the email suggestions:

```
List<WebElement> emailElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.aXS"));
for (WebElement emailElement : emailElements) {
    String email = emailElement.getText();
    System.out.println(email);
}
```

It takes approximately 20 seconds for each letter combination which is a lot.

How can I efficiently loop through and capture all email suggestions without such delays?

Is there a way to set a maximum wait time for findElements to avoid long waits when no suggestions are present?